# How to select jenkinsfile depending on branch name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a single large code base which is using for build and deployment apps for different countries.
Each country has its own unique building/deployment pipeline.
That's why I would like to specify dedicated jenkins script file for each country. For example, branch name contains `_UK_`, in this case I would like to use `_UK_Jenkinsfile`, if branch name containes `_US_` I'll create a new `_US_Jenkinsfile` etc.

So, the question is - how to specify Jenkinsfile depending on branch name?

[image]

Comment: Probably you can replace using `mv` the Jenkinsfile name in preStep or so according to your Jenkins job type, then extract the branch name using regex for the country name then get the `_UK_Jenkinsfile` in order to replace to Jenkinsfile in your workspace. So eventually, the `Jenkinsfile` in Script Path has nothing to do with in this pipeline.

Comment: I'd consider creation of separate Jenkins projects if jenkinfiles differ significantly. And if difference is only matter of couple strings, with addresses for example,you can use job parameters and a single file.

Comment: @Cергей will your branches be equal to `_UK_` or `_US_` or just contain this string somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter branches inside jenkinsfile by using `when` filter:

```
when {
  branch prod
}

when {
  expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(production|staging)/ }
}
```

More examples are [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)